# How does Spring Data know wicht store to back a repository with if multiple modules are used?

Tags: mongodb, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In a Spring Data project if I am using multiple types of repositories i.e JPA repository and Mongo repository and if I am extending `CrudRepository` then how does Spring Data know which store to choose for that repository? It can use JPA or Mongo. Is it based on the annotation **@Document** or **@Entity** added on every persisting entity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The decision which store a proxy created for a Spring Data repository interface is only made due to your configuration setup. Assume you have the following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.foo")
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.acme.foo")
class Config { }
```

This is going to blow up at some point as the interfaces in package `com.acme.foo` are both detected by the MongoDB and JPA infrastructure. To resolve this, both the JavaConfig and XML support allows you to define include and exclude filters so that you can either use naming conventions, additional annotations or the like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.foo", 
                       includeFilters = @Filter(JpaRepo.class))
@EnableMongoRepositories(base Packages = "com.acme.foo", 
                         includeFilters = @Filter(MongoRepo.class))
class Config { }
```

In this case, the two annotations `@JpaRepo` and `@MongoRepo` (to be created by you) would be used to selectively trigger the detection by annotating the relevant repository interfaces with them.

A real auto-detection is sort of impossible as it's hard to tell which store you're targeting solely from the repository interface declaration and at the point in time when the bean definitions are created we don't even know about any further infrastructure (an `EntityManager` or the like) yet.

Comment: Does that mean I need to mention in application config xml the classes to specific repository using include filters? Hypothetical question assuming the answer is Yes- If the same entity is used for storing in mongo as well as JPA repository then Do I need to write different repositories? ( This would be a good candidate for cross-store support may be but that's only limited to Mongo I guess)