# Define particular repository classes with EnableJpaRepositories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

I've been using `@EnableJpaRepositories` and I'm interested in opportunity of defining particular classes rather than packages. The reason behind this is the fact that I'm using multi-module project and at the moment have a core module which contains all repository definitions in a separate package:

```
core/repository/ - Here all repository definitions are stored
```

In other modules, which have dependency on core module, I use the following definition for fetching repositories:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="core.repository")
```

Apparently using this means fetching definitions for all the repositories which are under `core/repository` package. However, in some of the packages I need only some of the repositories, not all of them. For now I've moved every single repository definition to a separate package like:

```
core/repository/user
```

However I'm interested - is it really possible to define concrete repository classes, but not packages, something like that:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(baseClasses ="core.repository.UserRepository")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can customize loaded repositories by using includeFilters / excludeFilters param.

For example, you can define filters in your `EnableJpaRepositories` configuration:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "core.repository", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(MyModuleJpaRepo.Class))
```

and then mark every module repository with appropriate annotation:

```
@MyModuleJpaRepo
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> { … }
```

Here you can find example from spring-data author:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744045/1545775

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Maciej's answer

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.blah.repository", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                classes = {InventoryRepository.class}))
```